# Can we detect the laptop battery level using .net?

Tags: .net

I would like to detect the laptop battery level so that I can warn of low battery level using my application is it possible in .net ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? The operating system will do this for you already. Do you really need to replicate this?

Comment: the reason i want this code is because I need an app that will throw up a HUGE notification on the screen to bring to my wife's attention that the battery is low... :)

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at

[SystemInformation.PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

[SystemInformation.PowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.powerstatus.aspx) should help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code you can pretty much cut and paste: [Hangout with Sharp - C# - Battery Status Monitor](http://csapps.blogspot.com/2008/07/battery-status-monitor.html)

Answer (score 3):

Very first hit on google was this [article](http://csapps.blogspot.com/2008/07/battery-status-monitor.html). it appears to be what you are looking for. There is an even simpler version on [Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/11/12/1066558.aspx).